# How to re-install production Android app without leaving the beta test?

Tags: android, google-play, beta-testing

I have a production version and a beta version of my app. I'm one of my beta testers. I want to rollback the version on my phone to the production version so that I can configure some settings then reinstall the beta to ensure the upgrade is working properly.

I can't seem to figure out how to re-install the production version though. I've even tried leaving the beta test and I can't get Google Play to notice that I'm not a beta tester anymore. (deleted cache and data, rebooted phone, etc).

With iOS I can install the production version from the App Store and the test version from Test Flight. How do I do that on Android?

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure this out? Ran into a similar problem with internal tester, but so far the answer appears to be that you cannot do this.

Comment: How did you end up doing this?

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/245371/374079 I tried this and it worked @ZeeshanBadshah

Answer (score 0):

Use different account (new google account) from Google Play to download production, then enroll in beta and try to update. this is the quickest way.

Note: you probably facing this problem because you are an internal tester and a closed beta tester too.

Answer (score 0):

Toggling Developer settings helps to install the production and then switching  developer settings back on gives the option to update to beta once again.

EDIT: Actually this helps only to get the change to reflect if test track is paused or resumed

Found the fix here https://android.stackexchange.com/a/245371/374079